# $(this) doesnt work within a function?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a function that is called when a button is clicked. I want to traverse down the dom to get to a hidden input field that has some stored data that I need to access.

**Button**

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-danger delete-video-btn" onclick="delete_video()"><span class="icon-remove"><i> </i></span>Delete Video</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function delete_video() {
    alert('delete video is running');
    var thisUniqueID = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input[name="uniqueVideoID"]').val();
    alert(thisUniqueID);
    //alert("Are you sure you want to delete this video?");
}
```

But as it sits now, using (this) within my jquery doesn't work as intended. If I were to set it up like this it would work, but that doesn't work well with the code I have set up.

**This works, but not what I need**

```
jQuery('.delete-vide-btn').click(function() {
  var thisUniqueID = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input[name="uniqueVideoID"]').val();
  alert(thisUniqueID);
})
```

How can I get it to find the correct element and store the data, when the function runs, and not using the .click function?

Comment: when you call a function with no context like `delete_video()` then `this` refers to the global context (`window`). If you are using jQuery already, bind your events in code and not inline in the html.

Comment: It all depends on where and how the function is executed.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

Comment: Seriously,  `parent().parent().parent().find()` ?? Ick.

Comment: If you have jQuery, why are you doing `onclick="delete_video()"`?  What's wrong with `jQuery('.delete-vide-btn').click(function(){`?

Comment: wrote it like to test functionality. Thanks for the constructive comment though.

Comment: You may want to look at javascript `call` or `apply`

Comment: You may want to look at proper event handlers

Comment: You can save yourself some trouble if you just put the id in the function call. so onclick="delete_video(32)" then declare your function with function delete_video(id). This we you don't have to worry about breaking your code if you change your html markup.

Comment: Just as a side note, rather than use numerous `.parent()` calls you may want to look into [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
onclick="delete_video.call(this)"
```

and change nothing to your code.

**[Here an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ssAYj/)**

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for not trashing how I chose to write my code in your response.

Comment: My pleasur! Sure there is many way of coding, some are better, but the goal of SO is not to thrash other but answer the question while provinding optimal solution if needed, but i guess you got the "optimal" solution in the comments!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the context of "this" to the function:

```
onclick="delete_video(this)"
```

then....

```
function delete_video(something) {
    $this = something;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this function  

  function delete_video() {
        alert('delete video is running');
        var thisUniqueID = jQuery('.delete-vide-btn').parent().parent().parent().find('input[name="uniqueVideoID"]').val();
        alert(thisUniqueID);
        //alert("Are you sure you want to delete this video?");
    }
```